# Failed to build psutil ERROR: Could not build wheels for psutil, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: psutil, odoo-16

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for psutil
Running setup.py clean for psutil
Failed to build psutil
ERROR: Could not build wheels for psutil, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

This problem triggered when installing odoo 16 requirement in virtualenv at ubuntu-22.10

Answer (score 3):

**pip version was not compatiable with psutil**

```
sudo apt-get install gcc python3-dev
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
```

Then trying again to install psutil

```
pip install psutil
```